# Create ANT script to build on Tavis-CI and run JUnit tests on commit

Tags: java, git, ant, junit, travis-ci

I am developing a very simple application using Java, and using JUnit to test the application.

I need to be able to create an ANT script as well as a .travis.yml file so that my project can 1) build on Travis, and 2) Automatically run the JUnit tests on each commit.

You can see my revision history on GitHub, but the bigges issues that I have are that

1. I have NO CLUE what to do with the ANT script, other then have
   Eclipse auto-generate it
2. I don't know how to get Travis to run the tests automatically
3. I (believe) I need to include the JUnit jar locally, but don't know
   how to reference that

I need help getting this all to work, if you can provide instructions that would be great, if you can submit a pull request that would be even better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `build.xml` does not have a target `test`. You could add the line

```
script: ant <your_target>
```

to your `.travis.yml` file. E.g.

```
script: ant BackendSingletonTests
```

Comment: I think I added that now, but it's saying that I can't seem to find the junit jar: https://travis-ci.org/jvoller/SPDDB/builds/51029948

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18651161/travis-ci-with-ant-build-not-finding-junit

Comment: @Stega Birkner, the issue is that his repo is not public anymore, so I can't see his ANT script or .tavis.yml file. If you understand it, could you possibly submit a pull request?

Comment: The important part is the answer with the example project https://github.com/mplacona/java-junit-template-project

Comment: It now tries to compile, but doesn't seem to have imported the .jars: https://travis-ci.org/jvoller/SPDDB/builds/51269717 any ideas?